# "Hello! Python" Refactored Wumpus game - Empty list, stuck in loop

Tags: python

I'm following along in the "Hello! Python" book and I'm stuck on 'Listing 2.10 - The refactored wumpus game.'

I've created my functions and removed 'excess' code from the previous version of the game we've created by following the book.

Now I am getting stuck in a loop after the first call of the `print_caves` function and get returned a blank array. This is what I get:

```
Welcome to the Wumpus!
...
 === of the cave you wish to enter next
0 : []
1 : []
2 : []
...
19 : []
----------
```

Here is my code.

```
from random import choice

# functions , Convenience functions
def create_tunnel(cave_from, cave_to):
    """ Create a tunnel between cave_from and cave_to """
    caves[cave_from].append.cave(cave_to)
    caves[cave_to].append(cave_from)
def visit_cave(cave_number):
    """ Mark a cave as visited """
    visited_caves.append(cave_number)
    unvisited_caves.remove(cave_number)
def choose_cave(cave_list):
    """ Pick a cave from a list, provided that the cave has less than 3 tunnels """
    cave_number = choice(cave_list)
    while len(caves[cave_number]) >= 3:
        cave_number = choice(cave_list)
    return cave_number
def print_caves():
    """ Print out the current cave structure """
    for number in cave_numbers:
        print number, ":", caves[number]
    print '----------'
# functions , Cave-creation
def setup_caves(cave_numbers):
    """ Create the starting list of caves """
    caves = []
    for cave in cave_numbers:
        caves.append([])
    return caves
def link_caves():
    """ Make sure that all of the caves are connected by two way tunnels """
    while unvisited_caves != []:
        this_cave = choose_cave(visited_caves)
        next_cave = choose_cave(unvisited_caves)
    create_tunnel(this_cave, next_cave)
    visit_cave(next_cave)
def  finish_caves():
    """ Link the rest of the caves with one-way tunnels """
    for cave in cave_numbers:
        while len(caves[cave]) < 3:
        passage_to = choose_cave(cave_numbers)
        caves[cave].append(passage_to)  
# functions, player interaction
def print_location(player_location):
    """ Tell the player about where they are """
    print "--- You are in cave", player_location, "---"
    print ">>> From here, you can see caves:", caves[player_location], " <<<"
    if wumpus_location in caves[player_location]:
        print "I smell the Wumpus lurking nearby!"
def  get_next_location():
    """ Get the players next location """
    print "Which cave next?"
    player_input = raw_input(">")
    if (not player_input.isdigit() or
        int(player_input) not in caves[player_location]):
        print player_input + "?"
        print "I cant go that way"
        return None
    else:
        return int(player_input)    
#define variables
cave_numbers = range(0,20)
unvisited_caves = range (0,20)
visited_caves = []
caves = setup_caves(cave_numbers)
# welcome player 
print "0==[:::::::::::::> Welcome to the Wumpus! <::::::::::::]==0"
print ">>> You can see", len(cave_numbers), "caves! <<<"
print " === To play, just type a number"
print " === of the cave you wish to enter next"
# call functions
visit_cave(0)
print_caves()
link_caves()
print_caves()
finish_caves()
#define locations
wumpus_location = choice(cave_numbers)
player_location = choice(cave_numbers)
while player_location == wumpus_location:
    player_location = choice(cave_numbers)
while True:
    print_location(player_location)
    new_location = get_next_location()
    if new_location is not None:
        player_location = new_location
    if player_location == wumpus_location:
        print "Arrgh! You've been devoured by a Wumpus!"
        break
```

Comment: Is that your exact code? The indentation doesn't look right.

Comment: Thanks! I barely had time to try and fix the code showing up incorrectly before I had answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice you have a typo in `create_tunnel`: `caves[cave_from].append.cave(cave_to)` should have been `caves[cave_from].append(cave_to)`

The fact that this never caused an error suggests that something was wrong with your `link_caves` as that is the function that calls `create_tunnel`. I believe you want to move the last two lines into the `while` statement:

```
def link_caves():
    """ Make sure that all of the caves are connected by two way tunnels """
    while unvisited_caves != []:
        this_cave = choose_cave(visited_caves)
        next_cave = choose_cave(unvisited_caves)
        create_tunnel(this_cave, next_cave)
        visit_cave(next_cave)
```

The way it was, no cave was ever marked as visited, which means that the unvisited cave list never shrank, so the `while` statement runs forever.

If you make these two changes, your code will run:

```
0==[:::::::::::::> Welcome to the Wumpus! <::::::::::::]==0
>>> You can see 20 caves! <<<
 === To play, just type a number
 === of the cave you wish to enter next
0 : []
1 : []
2 : []
3 : []
4 : []
5 : []
6 : []
7 : []
8 : []
9 : []
10 : []
11 : []
12 : []
13 : []
14 : []
15 : []
16 : []
17 : []
18 : []
19 : []
----------
0 : [11, 12, 8]
1 : [18]
2 : [13]
3 : [9, 14, 15]
4 : [17]
5 : [12, 18]
6 : [15]
7 : [15]
8 : [0]
9 : [11, 3]
10 : [14]
11 : [0, 9]
12 : [0, 5, 16]
13 : [19, 2]
14 : [3, 19, 10]
15 : [3, 7, 6]
16 : [12]
17 : [19, 4]
18 : [5, 1]
19 : [14, 13, 17]
----------
--- You are in cave 14 ---
>>> From here, you can see caves: [3, 19, 10]  <<<
Which cave next?
>
```

Comment: Thanks! The code in the `link_caves` spanned a page break so the indention must have been skewed - or my interpretation haha!

Answer (score 0):

Your setup_caves function creates a bunch of empty caves.

Maybe you'd like to also link and finish caves before printing them?

---

The indentation for link_caves seems off.

Comment: Everything, as far as I can tell, is copied verbatim from the book. Including the printing order.

I will try and fix the indents on the copied code. Working on messing around with the `setup_caves`

Comment: see ramcdougal's answer for more details on how the indentation change will fix your code